# How can I get the manufacturer of GPU via command line in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, nvidia, graphics, gpu

I want to see the manufacturer of my GPUs. I know I can see this kind of information from "GPU-z" in Windows, but I'm using a server version of Ubuntu. I am not able to use this program.

How could I know the manufacturer of GPUs installed on my server? (Samsung, Hynix...etc.)

I've already tried some related operations like `nvidia-smi`, `sudo lshw -C display`, `lspci`. These actions are not providing information that I want.

Could you help me a little bit? cf. I am using nvidia graphic cards.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tell us what specific information you want! `lshw` does provide some information, but obviously you want something else. (It is not enough to refer to Windows programs, because you cannot expect us to know them.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To show the manufacturer of the GPU and other verbose information about the GPU, open the terminal and type:

```
lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
```

The `-vnn` options are:

`-v` –    **v**erbose output
`-nn` – display both the description and the **n**umber. display the PCI vendor code and the device code only as **n**umbers

The first line of the output has the name of the vendor, the model name/series and the pci id. Note the numbers enclosed by a pair of brackets having the form 1234:5678. Such a number is present for almost all graphics cards. The first 4-digit number (1234) indicates the vendor id and the second number (5678) indicates the pci id, which indicates the model of the graphics processing unit.

Comment: +1 -- This is a good answer, and I think almost the same information is provided by `lshw`, but the OP is not satisfied with the output of `sudo lshw -C display`. What information do they want?

Comment: Wont the above command only show NVIDIA/AMD, but not who manufactured the specific card - e.g. Gigabyte or Aorus?

Comment: `lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12` also shows who manufactured the card.